# Why properties are needed in C#?

Tags: c#, properties

In C#, properties could be used to return or reset the value of private members of a class. But people can also define methods to fulfill these, so my questions are:

1. why bother to introduce properties, why don't just use methods?
2. private members are intended to be accessed by the class only. then why are properties defined to modify the private member?

Comment: Why bother to introduce C, Java or C#, why don't just use Assembly?

Comment: In my opinion c# properties reduce code readability, there is a reason overwritten operators are evil... There great for math library's, other then that they should not be used. Properties encourage bad code.

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo what does operator overloading have to do with properties?

Comment: @Blorgbeard the syntax for accessing a property is a overloaded operator. instance.feild, instance = value;

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo totally agree that question is opinion based... Nice to know that there are people who dislike properties. (I like properties myself, but variety of opinions is what makes life interesting).

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo - The syntax for accessing a property is not an overloaded operator. Operators are things like `+` & `/`.

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo The `.` "operator" accesses either a field, property, method, inner class, extension method, etc.. I don't see why properties are the odd ones out there.

Comment: @Enigmativity I guess the point Anthony Raimondo tries to make is properties as overloaded operators can be abused to produce hard to reason about code (like `Count` property that go to some remote DB and takes a minute to run).  Note that I don't think it really valid reason to dislike properties in particular as languages I know don't provide any help with making sure that methods behave the way users *expect* them to behave. :(

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I have bad experience using properties. In the Unity3d scripting library properties were used for everything, the problem was that many of the innocent looking getters are expensive. Some return copys of arrays and other iterate over arrays and return the found value. Consequently there are many forums discussing what not do in the library and what methods to look out for. For a gaming library this is bad design.

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo - you can shorten that idea to "bad design is bad"... really nothing to do with nicely though out library that use properties in a way that prevents improper usage (and obviously returning arrays from properties is against C#/.Net guidelines, so that particular reason don't apply :) )

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov thats why i said it encourages bad code. If it wasnt an option it wouldnt be abused. Java for example limits features for this reason. I do agree with your point as well.

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo a count property might be expensive so properties are bad?  what do you assume in Java, assume every getXxx method is slow?

Comment: @Andy my opinion is based on being exposed to library's that misuse the feature. But i can see its benefits as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Methods represent actions (think of them as verbs) and properties represent data (think of them as nouns). Properties should not perform computationally complex logic or produce side effects. Methods on the other hand should.

Why use Properties:

- Properties are be used in data binding. For example, in ASP.Net MVC you use properties as part of Models.
- Properties provide fine-grained access control. For example, you can have read-only properties, by just providing a getter.
- It helps with debugging. For example, you can set a breakpoint on the property and the IDE will break when the value of the property is touched.

Comment: Properties compile to accessor methods, strictly speaking. They are convenient for public getters and private setters. It's mostly syntactic sugar if you are exclusively using them with a single backing field.

Comment: *Strictly speaking* those accessor methods are almost always inlined back into direct field accesses anyway. I don't really think it's relevant to this question how the compiler/jitter converts the C# language abstraction of a property into machine code.

Comment: @Blorgbeard that's true, but I think the semantic differences between properties and methods are more important than the technical differences.

Comment: @Andy that was intended to be my point too :)